# How to add a new record in kendo grid with enter key press event

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, keypress, kendo-grid, enter

i have developed a simple web application using some **kendo ui** tools.

in there i have used **kendo grid** tool to view and insert data of product details.

but my problem is in **edit mode**(when i insert a new record) when i press the **enter key** i need to go to the next cell(**next column of the same row**) and after the last column of then go to the next row(**new record**).

here is the code im using for grid in my **view** "index.cshtml"

```
    button class="k-button" id="batchGrid">
    Batch Edit</button>
<div id="example" class="k-content">
    <div id="batchgrid">
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    $("#batchGrid").click(function () {
        var crudServiceBaseUrl = "http://demos.kendoui.com/service",
                        dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                            transport: {
                                read: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                update: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Update",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                destroy: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Destroy",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                create: {
                                    url: crudServiceBaseUrl + "/Products/Create",
                                    dataType: "jsonp"
                                },
                                parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                        return { models: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            batch: true,
                            pageSize: 20,
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    id: "ProductID",
                                    fields: {
                                        ProductID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                        ProductName: { validation: { required: true} },
                                        UnitPrice: { type: "number", validation: { required: true, min: 1} },
                                        Discontinued: { type: "boolean" },
                                        UnitsInStock: { type: "number", validation: { min: 0, required: true} }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

        $("#batchgrid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            navigatable: true,
            filterable: true,
            pageable: true,
            height: 430,
            width: 300,
            toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
            columns: [
                            "ProductName",
                            { field: "UnitPrice", title: "Unit Price", format: "{0:c}", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "UnitsInStock", title: "Units In Stock", width: "130px" },
                            { field: "Discontinued", width: "130px" },
                            { command: ["destroy"], title: "&nbsp;", width: "100px"}],
            editable: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

how to handle **enter key press event** in kendo grid and go through columns and rows?

please help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code.

```
$("#batchgrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {

            var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var cellIndex = $(this).index();
            $("input").on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin($("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent())));
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: i'm really sory sir but the problem is still there.i think the problem is combo box.when i press enter in textbox it will jump to the next cell no matter what is there but when i press enter in a combobox or checkbox or dropdown it will not work fine as in textbox.if you can please give me a appropriate solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it help you to move next cell while enter keypress,

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#batchGrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {
            var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var cellIndex = $(this).index();
            window.onkeydown = function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#batchGrid").data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin($("#batchGrid").data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent())));

                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: i tried your code but it doesn't give any positive feedback.when i press the enter key it doesn't move to the next cell.kindly please give your attention here..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $("#batchgrid").on("click", "td", function (e) {

            var rowIndex = $(this).parent().index();
            var cellIndex = $(this).index();
            $(".k-textbox").on("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid").editCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").next().focusin($("#batchgrid").data("kendoGrid").closeCell($(".k-grid-content").find("table").find("tbody").find("tr:eq(" + rowIndex + ")").find("td:eq(" + cellIndex + ")").parent())));
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: so far its working if i used only text boxes but the problem is when i press the enter key in a combo box or check box it is not working properly.how to solve that?

Comment: i'm really sory sir but the problem is still there.i think the problem is combo box.when i press enter in textbox it will jump to the next cell no matter what is there but when i press enter in a combobox or checkbox or dropdown it will not work fine as in textbox.if you can please give me a appropriate solution.